# Hibernate toString() method lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, proxy, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I'm new to Hibernate, and I don't fully understand the lazy loading process. Specifically, say I have a class with proxy objects. If I define a method, such as toString(), that will print data--including data about the proxy objects--what happens? Do the proxy objects get initialized and why? Are there ways to interact with the proxy objects or any way to create methods that won't initialize the objects when used?